# ¿Por qué se demora una variable en ser definida?

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando WebAssembly y trato de importar algunas funciones de el archivo, aqui está el código javascript:

```
var wmodules;

fetch("main.wasm")
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {}))
    .then(result => result.instance)
    .then(main);

function main(wasm) {
    wmodules = wasm;      // No quiero escribir TODO el programa  
                          // dentro de esta función
}

const { add, sub, mul, div } = wmodules.exports;
```

Cuando hago correr el codigo con `python -m http.server` lo primero que me aparece en la consola del navegador es `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined`, pero cuando escribo en la consola `wmodules.exports.add` me aparece que sí existe la función.
Aquí coloco una foto de la consola de chrome:
[image: consola de chrome]

y aquí dejo el codigo de WebAssembly:

```
(module
    (func $add (param $a i32) (param $b i32) (result i32)
        get_local $a
        get_local $b
        i32.add)
    (export "add" (func $add))
    (func $sub (param $a i32) (param $b i32) (result i32)
        get_local $a
        get_local $b
        i32.sub)
    (export "sub" (func $sub))
    (func $mul (param $a i32) (param $b i32) (result i32)
        get_local $a
        get_local $b
        i32.mul)
    (export "mul" (func $mul))
    (func $div (param $a i32) (param $b i32) (result i32)
        get_local $a
        get_local $b
        i32.div_s)
    (export "div" (func $div)))
```

**No busco saber que significa ese error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined), lo que busco es por qué cuando carga la pagina, la variable me aparece "undefined" y después cuando la uso en la consola aparece definida.**

Comment: No busco saber que significa ese error, lo que busco es por qué cuando carga la pagina, la variable me aparece "undefined" y después cuando la uso en la consola aparece definida.

Answer (score 2):

La función `main` se ejecuta después de

```
const { add, sub, mul, div } = wmodules.exports;
```

debido a que la ejecución es asíncrona.
Y debido a eso, la variable `wmodules` no se define hasta la ejecución de `main`.

Comment: Y ¿como puedo cambiar eso para que sea síncrona?

Comment: Es posible que te sirvan los operadores `async` y `await`, sin embargo te recomiendo revisar la compatibilidad en los navegadores.